# yii framework: cannot login to gii

Tags: php, yii

I just following the yii-blog.pdf from the documentation, when I tried to login to gii, it keep showing me the login form all the time.

I create a virtual host for this like http://yii.blog 
and then tried to access from http://yii.blog/index.php?r=gii

in the config/main.php

```
'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'12345',
                //'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','yii.blog')
    ),
),
```

when I type the wrong password the form could say "Incorrect password."
but when I type the correct one, it didn't say any error and it keep showing me the login form.

I am using YII 1.1.5

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did any of our answers help solve your problem?

Comment: just installing new xampp and it works. I have no idea why it wont work on older xampp

Answer (score 2):

I have had issues with Chrome with this, restarting Chrome worked for me. Firefox had no problems at all.

Answer (score 2):

Logging into Gii requires the use of PHP server sessions, so testing in another browser or clearing cache and cookies helps rule out issues on the browser end wich may interfere with session handling.  However, if that fails, you may need to check your PHP configuration:

- Use command line statement `php -i |grep session.save`
- Save a file containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on your server and view it in your browser, then do an in-page search for "session.save"

In my case it turned out to be a misconfiguration in my PHP.ini: the default session path wasn't configured. I edited the config file for my server and set a valid path for *session.save_path*. I uncommented the relevant line in my default **PHP.ini** and I was able to login to Gii with the valid password after including the following two lines--though other session configurations are possible.

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a session/cookie issue. Try restarting the browser like Don mentioned, or using a different browser. Also a cache-clearing refresh (Ctrl+F5) might do the trick.

I also had to set up URL aliases to make Gii work, since I am using URL rewrite rules, like so:

```
'components'=>array(
  'urlManager'=>array(
    'rules'=>array(
      'gii'=>'gii',
      'gii/<controller:[\w\-]+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
      'gii/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
    )
  )
)
```

Try this if you using the urlManager (which it actually looks like you are not).

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me.
I removed the password all together.

```
    'configWeb' => array(
    // Modules
     'modules' => array(
        'gii' => array(
            'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password' => false,
        ),
    ),
```

We're using multiple config files for different environments like development, staging, and production. When I had problems, I was probably editing the wrong file anyways.

Answer (score 0):

One year after ..... I had this error too. In my case I had two versions of PHP. First I installed Wamp 2.0i with PHP 5.3.0. With this PHP version I installed yii 1.1.8 and started some test projects.

After that I copied the folder 5.2.5 of PHP from another WAMP installation in another machine. when I select PHP 5.2.5 in the WAMP tray menu selector I cann't connect to gii exactly as nightingale2k1 said.

Answer (score 0):

deleting my domain **cookies** of my browser fixed that issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Check in your php.ini as to what dir you have set for session.save_path,

```
php -i | grep session.save_path
```

and then make sure that folder is writable by your web user/group.

example:

```
sudo chgrp www-data /opt/lampp/temp/
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean cookies, or more specific all PHPSESSID's. Sometimes it clutters withdomains of upper level.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (in 'Yii Example App' login work successfuly but Gii not and without any error message). after hours I solve problem by changing `php.ini` of my Denwer server:

```
session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

by

```
session.save_path = "d:\tmp"
```

P.S. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my `session` component where I had set `cookieMode` to `none`:

```
'components'=>array(
    /* ... */
    'session' => array (
        'autoStart' => false,
        'cookieMode' => 'none', /* This means gii cannot set cookies! */
    ),
    /* ... */
);
```

Here `cookieMode` should be set to `only` instead:

```
'components'=>array(
    /* ... */
    'session' => array (
        'autoStart' => false,
        'cookieMode' => 'only', /* "only" will allow gii to set cookies */
    ),
    /* ... */
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write any password you want to the config file – look for it here: /protected/config/main.php, the section you need will look

```
'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'generatorPaths'=>array('bootstrap.gii'),
        'password'=>'yourPassword',
    ),
)
```